# copy association rules extracted using Orange 3 GUI data mining tool

Tags: data-mining, orange

I want to induce Association Rules and save it to a file for further processing. I'm doing this through Orange graphical data mining tool.

There's option to save as Html or pdf. The problem is that only subset of the rules are copied! It's written at the end of the copied file "+9900 rules"

So how can I copy all of the rules??

Comment: This question does not seem programming-related, and would probably be better asked in some other Stack Exchange. Perhaps this one?
 https://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: thanks I will delete it and ask in  stats.stackexchange.com

Comment: Perhaps ask on [DataScience.SE](http://datascience.stackexchange.com) as [Orange's website advises](https://orange.biolab.si/community/).

Comment: @Rawlerb'stats.SE' is inappropriate. This is not a statistics question (nor a programming question), but a orange bug report / feature request that *only* should go to the orange people themselves.